# How to automate deleting temp internet explorer files in user profile Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, user-profile, windows-2000

I finding the program for automate deleting internet explorer files in Windows Server user profiles. User profile temp files are located here C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\

I need to add this program in task schedule. I was used simple ERASE windows command, but it's don't working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Cleanmgr.exe from command line. You can find the options here:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315246